# Get List URL in SharePoint Designer 2010 workflow using substring action

Tags: sharepoint-designer, designer-workflow

I need to log current LIST URL from a SharePoint Designer workflow 2010. Now in the workflow context I have Item URL and current site URL but no List URL. How to get it?? I cant use Site URL and then append ../List/List name.

I have sub string action in Workflow. Can Anyone help me in extracting the URL using Sub string action. Thanks!!

Comment: Are you working with List workflow or Reusable workflow?

Answer (score 1):

Go to C`urrent List as Data Source` and Select `Path for ID of Current Item : ID` and you get the relative list path.

Sub string complexity is not required.